# mod_rewrite redirect to URL with propietary protocol

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Apache 2.2 with mod_rewrite.

Is there a way to force mod_rewrite to rewrite the entire URL, including protocol? I know it will automatically rewrite the whole URL if the redirect contains `http://` at the beginning but I'm trying to redirect to a URL that uses a proprietary protocol: `fcp://`

When I add it in as the redirect it just redirects to the URL of my server with the rewrite appended like so:

```
http://www.example.com/fcp://@mailstaff....
```

Can I configure the module to treat `fcp://` as a full URL so I don't run in to this?

**UPDATE:** Here is the code I am using:

```
RewriteCond ${externals:$2|Unknown} !Unknown
RewriteRule ^(internal|external)/(.*)/? ${externals:$2} [R=301,NE,L,NS]
```

Inside the `externals` RewriteMap, I have a line like this:

```
firstclass-email        fcp://@mailstaff.example.com/
```

When I go to trigger the RewriteRule by going to:

```
http://example.com/internal/firstclass-email
```

It will incorrectly redirect me to here:

```
http://example.com/fcp://@mailstaff.example.com/
```

If I change the protocol part from `fcp://` to `http://`, Apache will realize it's an absolute URL and work correctly. I want Apache to recognize `fcp://` should also be absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache can only handle the most common URL schemes like `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `mailto`, etc. Custom URL schemes are not recognized as such but handled as a URL path.

See the `is_absolute_uri` function in the [source code of mod_rewrite.c](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c) for details on what schemes are supported.

Comment: That's what I feared :( Is there any way to change this in userland?

Comment: Try to use a script that handles the redirect instead of Apache.

Comment: "Apache can only handle..." - strictly speaking, it is *mod_rewrite* that can only handle the most common URL schemes. Other modules (like mod_alias: `Redirect` / `RedirectMatch`) appear to "handle" them OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RedirectMatch` instead of `RewriteRule`.

Check [How to handle mod-rewrite with a custom url scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26930129/299726) for the explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
RewriteRule ^/yourUrl$ fcp://otherUrl [RL]
```

Comment: That’s rather a question than an answer. But anyways, have you tried that on your own?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but it's my suggestion of what to try. Do you see something wrong with it?

Comment: I posed it as a question/answer because he didn't list what RewriteRule's he was currently using.

Comment: Yes, see the second half of my question for the result. It just adds the substitution part to the server's domain name.

Comment: Please post the actual RewriteRule that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question - but I can answer. I had the same problem. This can be solved with two redirects.

```
Redirect /restore1 fcp://example.com/restore

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile.....
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|.....
RewriteRule ^restore/(.*)$ http://example.com/restore1/$1
```