# How to handle mod-rewrite with a custom url scheme?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, custom-url

So here's my problem : I'm trying to do a redirection on a webpage with the htaccess file. This redirection will be towards a custom URL (i.e not something ike "http://..." but something like "myurl://...).

For now, I'm trying this on a little local apache server, in which I have a index.html page, a "test" directory and in this directory a .htaccess file and a test.html file.

Here's what's inside the .htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ myurl://test$1 [R=302]
```

I think the problem probably comes from here, as I'm totally new at this and this is the first time I try to write into a .htaccess file. So, if this is not the proper way to do this, what is the proper way to do this then ?

Thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is related to the `RewriteRule` itself that checks the url scheme. From the source code [mod_rewrite.c](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c) it reads only a subset of schemes:

Protocols Recognized by Mod_Rewrite

- ajp:// - Apache JServ Protocol
- balancer:// - Apache Load Balancer
- fcgi://
- ftp:// - File Transfer Protocol
- gopher:// - Gopher (protocol)
- http:// - Hypertext Transfer Protocol
- https:// - Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure
- ldap:// - Lightweight Directory Access Protocol
- mailto: - The mailto URI scheme
- news: - News Protocol
- nntp:// - Network News Transfer Protocol
- scgi://
- ws://
- wws://

Indeed you can use `RedirectMatch` that doesn't check the protocol as follows:

```
RedirectMatch /(.*) myurl://$1
```

Comment: This should be the right answer! Worked for my app thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps I'm missing something but the prefix of the URL is the protocol. The client browsing to the url has an application bound to this protocol. HTTP(S) = Browser, MAGNET = torrent client, MAILTO = Email client, etc..

So if your client is configured to actually use that kind of url you will contact your server either in http or https.. so I'm guessing you can't check on protocol.. ?

If apache is accepting your request I guess you can check the entire url using %{SCRIPT_URI}.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "so I'm guessing you can't check on protocol.. ?"
Actually, this will then be used on Windows Phone, and the "myurl://" has been registered in an app I developped, so when the browser calls this url, my app opens automatically

Comment: I mean that 'myurl' isn't a protocol known by apache. You will still contact your webserver using HTTP or HTTPS. So it's your application that will contact the apache webserver and not the browser?

Comment: Oh okay I understand. No, it's the browser that will call the apache server, and the url should redirect to my app. So what you're saying is that the server doesn't understand the protocol, and therefore, doesn't correctly redirect ?

Comment: No. I'm saying that the client's browser will not use the browser to contact your apache server using 'myurl://myhost.com/..'. Therefor this request will never reach your server.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, I'll try something esle then

Comment: "Perhaps I'm missing something" - it's not necessarily the client that has a problem with the protocol... it's Apache mod_rewrite that has a problem with unrecognised protocols in general and results in an invalid response being sent back to the client (the client doesn't even see the intended protocol). mod_rewrite ends up seeing the _substitution_ as a relative URL and prefixes the scheme and hostname from the current request, so you end up with a malformed redirect to something like `http://example.com/myurl://testfoo`.